# input from rhandsontable in shiny issues

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(wellPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
    actionButton(inputId="enter",label="enter")
  ))
))


server=function(input,output){

  DF=data.frame(Code=c(1,2,3),Amount=c(NA,NA,NA))

  output$hot=renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(DF,readOnly=F))

  observeEvent(input$enter, {
    DF=hot_to_r(input$hot)
    print(DF)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Hi, I want to input from rhansontable which is in shiny.
However, When column's cells are full of NA, the cells cannot be edited.
can these be solved? Thanks

---

also that when I changed the data type like this

`output$hot=renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(DF,readOnly=F)  %>% hot_col(col = "Amount", type = "numeric"))`

the values in the cells can be edited. However, when I use 'DF=hot_to_r(input$hot)', the values seems like not saving in the DF.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#column_types) link, you will have to convert NA to characters. So you need to do something like this:

```
 server=function(input,output){

    DF=data.frame(Code=c(1,2,3),Amount=as.character(c(NA,NA,NA)))

    output$hot=renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = FALSE) %>%
                                     hot_col("Amount", type = "numeric"))

    observeEvent(input$enter, {
      DF=hot_to_r(input$hot)
      print(DF)
    })
  }
```

Comment: No, I want the cell remain empty in view.but I want to be able to edit the cells ~

Comment: Changing it to character will still show an empty cell in the view, only while you try editing the cell it shows NA as in the previous case.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the DF

```
  DF=data.frame(Code=c(1,2,3),Amount=c(NA,NA,NA))

  DF[is.na(DF)] <- ""
```